# Item Delete not deleting item in Variation Site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, timer-jobs, variations

I have a site which is actually a root site for Variation site under `http://mywebapp/en` and there is a derived site `http://mywebapp/ar` for English and Arabic sites respectively.

Whenever i create a page inside my root site `http://mywebapp/en` and run the job **Variations Propagate Page Job Definition** the page is immediately got promoted to `http://mywebapp/ar` and i can see that page. However, when i delete a page from `http://mywebapp/en` and run the job again, its not deleting from `http://mywebapp/ar` site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In case that a page in the source variation label has been deleted, all relationships list entries for the variation group of the deleted item are recycled - means neither the item which was deleted in the source label nor the items in the target labels are variation hierarchy items after the delete.

More information about [variation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/11/25/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-10-restructuring-the-hierarchy/).